# Include package in Spark local mode

Tags: python, apache-spark, pytest, pyspark

I'm writing some unit tests for my Spark code in python. My code depends on [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). In production I use `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.0.3` to submit my python script.

I'm using [pytest](http://pytest.org/latest/) to run my tests with Spark in `local` mode:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('myapp').setMaster('local[1]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

My question is, since `pytest` isn't using `spark-submit` to run my code, how can I provide my `spark-csv` dependency to the python process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use your config file spark.driver.extraClassPath to sort out the problem.
Spark-default.conf

and add the property

```
 spark.driver.extraClassPath /Volumes/work/bigdata/CHD5.4/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-csv_2.11-1.1.0.jar:/Volumes/work/bigdata/CHD5.4/spark-1.4.0-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/commons-csv-1.1.jar
```

After setting the above you even don't need packages flag while running from shell.

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
    df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='false').load(BASE_DATA_PATH + '/ssi.csv')
```

Both the jars are important, as spark-csv depends on `commons-csv` apache jar. The `spark-csv` jar you can either build or download from mvn-site.